# Sticky navigation bar - not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

## Question

I want the navBar to stick conditionally on scroll. However there are bugs I can not quite diagnose, as I am new to jQuery. What is preventing the nav bar from sticking conditionally on scroll?

The jQuery in the jsfiddle below will not run correctly, and after trying for awhile to make it work, I cannot seem to make it run. I've looked at other examples of this but I'd rather not change the jQuery entirely until I know the reason that my code does not work. I will not link the HTML as it full of Lorem Ipsum test text body. It is found in the JSFiddle link.

What is the error in the javascript that isn't making the navBar apply the sticky class?

## Javascript

```
var navTop = $(".nav").offset().top;

var stickyNav = function(){
  if ($(window).scrollTop() >= navTop){
    $(".nav").addClass(".sticky")
  } else {
    $(".nav").removeClass(".sticky")
  }
};

stickyNav();

$(window).scroll(function(){
    stickyNav();
};
```

## CSS

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.mainHeader {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  background-color: rgb(62, 65, 66);
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Helvetica Nue";
}

.navigation {
  width 100%;
  height 10%;
  background-color: rgb(89, 127, 143);
  position: relative;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/11u1bj5j/

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What is the error in the javascript that isn't making the navBar apply the sticky class? I edited this into the question if it was not clear.

Comment: Nav class name is navigation not nav u are using .nav in jquery

Comment: That makes sense, doesn't it? This is my second iteration, I glanced over that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some bugs in your js code. Firstly, `.nav` should be `nav` since your `<nav>` element has a class of `navigation`. So, we'll grab it by the tag name instead. Secondly, `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` don't need the period before the class name.

Here's the updated javascript:

```
var navTop = $("nav").offset().top;

var stickyNav = function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= navTop){
        $("nav").addClass("sticky");
    } else {
        $("nav").removeClass("sticky");
    }
};

stickyNav();

$(window).scroll(function(){
    stickyNav();
});
```

Here's an updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gdm0hf73/).

Comment: As mentioned in another comment, I must have glazed over the exclusion of the dots in the documentation. Thank you for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you are adding/removing classes wrongly with jquery should be

```
.addClass("sticky") / .removeClass("sticky")
```

same with `nav` selection, there were some other small css problems too

here is [working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/11u1bj5j/6/)

Comment: The CSS problems were kind of embarrassing. When making this iteration in fiddle I made some mistakes that weren't in the iteration I had in my actual environment. Thank you!